# Join display not working while mirror does

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

Basically the title. When I connect an external display through HDMI, if I set the "mirror" option in the display settings everything works as expected. But, if I select "join", the external display remains black (although it's detected, because when I connect it the main screen goes black for a second, as if it was preparing for projection). I've tried different displays as well, but the behavior is the same. Any tips? Thanks!

Useful info: I'm running Ubuntu 22.10 on a Framework laptop 12 i5-1240P. The iGPU is an Intel Iris. I use the usb-c port to connect the HDMI cable with the official adapter.

Update: I've upgraded to Ubuntu 23.04 and now the behavior is slightly changed. As soon as I select the "join" option, the second display does not remain black anymore, but it starts showing the (mirrored) desktop scrolling incredibly fast from right to left.

Comment: Basically the title?   The *title* may not be viewable when people are reading your question, so details should be complete in your actual question (*not all readers use large screens on modern PCs & the same browser; so don't make people press BACK & re-read the title, then re-enter the page!*). Are you using Ubuntu 22.10 Desktop? or a *flavor*?  Also don't forget [Ubuntu 22.10 will soon be EOL](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/06/14/ubuntu-22-10-kinetic-kudu-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-20-2023/)

Comment: I'm sorry if the first sentence was confusing, but I think the body of the question contains the description of the problem with all the necessary details. If there is anything I need to add, please let me know. I'm using Ubuntu 22.10 desktop.

Comment: Following your reminder about 22.10 being close to EOL, I've updated to Ubuntu 23.04, also in hope that it would solve the problem. Now, when I join monitors the second display does not remain black, but it starts showing the (mirrored) desktop scrolling incredibly fast from right to left. I wouldn't call this a progress, but it's something new for sure :)

Comment: If you're now on 23.04 & the situation varies to your current question (*don't forget this is a Q&A site and not a forum, answers will be to your question itself*) please amend the question. This question is still 22.10 & second monitor remaining black.  Comments are intended just for that; comments about the original question (to *Original Poster* or prior commenter) & get removed once addressed as they're not part of the question itself.

Comment: I updated the question, sorry for the improper use of comments.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after upgrading debian.
I'm running `amdgpu` driver on Lenovo Thinkpad P14s laptop.

I solved it by setting the refresh rate of the external monitor to 59.96 Hz (by default it was set to 59.95Hz). Very strange.